# Get only the pr form a git branch in concourse

Tags: devops, concourse, concourse-pipeline, concourse-git-resource

```
- name: databricks-repo
  type: git
  icon: github-circle
  source:
  uri: xyz.git
  branch: master
  private_key: ((key))
```

I am trying to do a code scan only to the PR from the git branch. the above code gets me only the code from the branch not the pr

Answer (score -1):

Use the [Github PR Resource](https://github.com/telia-oss/github-pr-resource) to accomplish this. This is the example they provide on the project page:

```
resource_types:
- name: pull-request
  type: docker-image
  source:
    repository: teliaoss/github-pr-resource

resources:
- name: pull-request
  type: pull-request
  check_every: 24h
  webhook_token: ((webhook-token))
  source:
    repository: itsdalmo/test-repository
    access_token: ((github-access-token))

jobs:
- name: test
  plan:
  - get: pull-request
    trigger: true
    version: every
  - put: pull-request
    params:
      path: pull-request
      status: pending
  - task: unit-test
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: alpine/git, tag: "latest"}
      inputs:
        - name: pull-request
      run:
        path: /bin/sh
        args:
          - -xce
          - |
            cd pull-request
            git log --graph --all --color --pretty=format:"%x1b[31m%h%x09%x1b[32m%d%x1b[0m%x20%s" > log.txt
            cat log.txt
    on_failure:
      put: pull-request
      params:
        path: pull-request
        status: failure
  - put: pull-request
    params:
      path: pull-request
      status: success
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it is there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you are linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)